# Get Numbers from Days of Week

Tags: javascript

How to get the number from the Day of weeks. My solution is working but is there any better way to achieve this. Thanks

I have an object

```
{
  id:1,
  weeks: 'Mon,Tue,Thu' 
}
```

I want to convert it to

```
{
  id:1,
  weeks:'124'
}
```

Comment: The input you have added to your answer together with my code, is not the input you had specified in your original question. There are now spaces before the commas. Please clarify what all possible variation can be in your input, or otherwise could you remove that last edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `indexOf` to get the day number, and object spread to create a new object (if that is OK, otherwise just assign to `obj.week`):

```js
var obj = {id:1, week:'Mon,Tue,Thu'};
obj = {
    ...obj,
    week: obj.week.split(',').map(x =>
        ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'].indexOf(x) + 1
    ).join("")
};

console.log(obj);
```

Alternatively, you could use `replace` with callback:

```js
var obj = {id:1, week:'Mon,Tue,Thu'};
obj = {
    ...obj,
    week: obj.week.replace(/(\w+),?/g, (_, x) =>
        ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'].indexOf(x) + 1
    )
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I tried your code, it seems its not working as expected. I've updated my question.

Comment: I believe there is a gap after the string "Mon " which needs to be removed.  Anyways Thank you.

Comment: @BhokluSingh use x.trim() to remove space

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `.indexOf()` like in other answer. There is also other sanitisation good to be taken care of, like trimming day names with possible leading / trailing spaces, filtering out invalid outcome and so on.

Here is the code for basic idea of handling your use case:

```js
const obj = { id: 1, week: "Mon,Tue,Thu" };

const convertToNum = (
  a = "",
  b = a.split(","),
  c = ["None", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
) => {
  return b.map((d) => c.indexOf(d.trim())).filter((e) => e !== -1);
};

console.log(convertToNum(obj.week));
```